# Create Binary Variable based on lag in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a binary/indicator variable based on lagged observation. I have a variable X1. The raw data looks like below. It's a sample data. Original data has close to 10K records.

```
X1
Diagnosis
1
2
3
4
Treatment
1
2
3
```

I want the output to look like this :

```
X1           NewVar
Diagnosis    Diagnosis
1            Diagnosis
2            Diagnosis
3            Diagnosis 
4            Diagnosis 
Treatment    Treatment 
1            Treatment  
2            Treatment
3            Treatment
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Show what steps you've taken to resolve this. Show us the code and which specific part is causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `cumsum`. The `cumsum` can create a new group each time a `Diagnosis` or `Treatment` appears. Then the `NewVar` in each group will take the value of first `X1` in this group:

```
library(dplyr)

dtf %>%
    mutate(g = cumsum(X1 == 'Diagnosis' | X1 == 'Treatment')) %>%
    group_by(g) %>%
    mutate(NewVar = X1[1]) %>%
    ungroup() %>% select(-g)
# # A tibble: 9 x 2
#          X1    NewVar
# <fctr>    <fctr>
# 1 Diagnosis Diagnosis
# 2         1 Diagnosis
# 3         2 Diagnosis
# 4         3 Diagnosis
# 5         4 Diagnosis
# 6 Treatment Treatment
# 7         1 Treatment
# 8         2 Treatment
# 9         3 Treatment
```

the `dtf` in above code:

```
> dput(dtf)
structure(list(X1 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "Diagnosis", "Treatment"), class = "factor")), .Names = "X1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `data.table`.  After converting to 'data.table' (`setDT(dtf)`, get the cumulative sum of logical vector based on 'X1' values as characters and assign 'NewVar' as the first element of 'X1' (`X1[1]`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dtf)[,  NewVar := X1[1], cumsum(grepl('^[A-Za-z]+$', X1))]
dtf
#          X1    NewVar
#1: Diagnosis Diagnosis
#2:         1 Diagnosis
#3:         2 Diagnosis
#4:         3 Diagnosis
#5:         4 Diagnosis
#6: Treatment Treatment
#7:         1 Treatment
#8:         2 Treatment
#9:         3 Treatment
```